# Where do the Spring Security Authentication and Principal objects come from in a controller's methods?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have some methods in a Spring Boot `@RestController` that magically seem to have access to the Spring Security `Authentication` or `Principal` objects when I add them as arguments. I am wondering, how do my methods work with these arguments? Where do they come from?
Here is an example:

```
@GetMapping("/someEndpoint")
public ObjectNode someEndpoint(Authentication authentication) {
    ...
    CustomAuthentication customAuthentication = (CustomAuthentication) authentication;
    logger.debug("Name: {}", customAuthentication.getName());
    ...
}
```

or

```
@GetMapping("/anotherEndpoint)
public ObjectNode anotherEndpoint(Principal principal) {

    logger.debug(principal.getName());
    ...
}
```

It isn't just these `Authentication` and `Principal` objects either. I've also seen `HttpServletRequest` and other arguments sometimes in these controller endpoints. Where do they come from and why are they optional? Is there a list somewhere of these objects I can get in my methods?

Comment: This answer answers the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29410196/1191849

Answer (score -1):

Answer to all your questions are available in the *Spring Reference Documentation*

For [Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.1/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-authentication) related question do read through to understand on a highlevel how it is made available in the session. Read on [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.1/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-abstractprocessingfilter)

Read through the documentation for the list of supported controller method arguments [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments)

- [Spring MVC Reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc)
- [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.1/reference/html5/)

Comment: Do you have any specific place to look in the docs about how the arguments are injected? I've read through MVC and Security docs so many times over the past week and haven't found it. This answer's link https://stackoverflow.com/a/29410196/1191849 explains it in pretty good detail, I just haven't been able to find anything like this in the docs.

Comment: (I'm looking for a lower level "how", I am really freaked out by all the Spring "magic" and want to know what is really happening)

Comment: Probably your question does not mention the research done or the code references you were looking for. My answer is specific to the question topic and also provides the list you were looking for. I understand that you found my answer not useful , but would want to get the point across that my answer is not wrong.